# Linker cannot find libpthread

Tags: linker, ld, pthreads

I am trying to build 32bit versions of two programs, and both shows the same error message

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Glibc-2.17-32bit/lib/libpthread.so.0
```

I certainly understand why it cannot find it, as I moved Glibc dir from the above path to:

```
/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux-32bit/Glibc-2.17/lib/libpthread.so.0
```

However, I have no idea as to why ld is looking for libpthread in this wrong path. I have a bunch of symbolic links to Glibc lib files in /usr/lib32, but these are all correct, with the one responsible to libpthread pointing to the second path above. I executed ldconfig but to no avail

When I tried to build the first program, I thought some libraries that I was passing to configure had this old path hard linked on it, and so it was the cause.

However, when I run configure on the second program, I don't need to pass any library to it for the same error message to show up, so the cause is likely other.

So, I am open to any suggestion as to why is ld looking for libpthread in the old directory.

Answer (score 0):

`ld` finds libraries through `.so` files (which are either symlinks or linker scripts). The error you’re getting suggests that it’s finding a `libpthread.so` which points to the old location of `libpthread.so.0`; you need to update that to point to the new location.